# Header component is not registered first time properly

Tags: vue.js, layout, vue-component

I want to showing profile on click for logged in user, when i click to that, my profile page is rendered, but header content is not loaded properly, i checked in console, it shown me an error, did you register component properly. but if i refresh or reload page, header content is showing and console error also cleared that showing did you register component properly.
please help me where i mistaken.

header.vue

```
    <template>
    <div>
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>Free shipping on all orders over $100</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="links" v-if="!this.$page.auth.user">
                                <inertia-link :href="route('login.page')"> Log in </inertia-link>
                                <InertiaLink :href="route('RegistrationForm')">Register</InertiaLink>
                            </div>
                            <div class="id-link" v-else>
                                <div class="profile-content" @click="OpenProfile"> <b-link href="#"> Welcome {{this.$page.auth.user.name}} </b-link> </div>
                                  <div class="profile" v-if="expanded">
                                    <b-img src="/images/profile.jpg" alt="image"></b-img>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li> <b-button variant="primary"> <inertia-link :href="route('User-Profile')" method="get"> Profile </inertia-link> </b-button> </li>
                                        <li> <b-button variant="primary"> <inertia-link :href="route('logout')" method="post"> Logout </inertia-link> </b-button> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>                                                 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="navbar">
                            <ul>
                             <li> <InertiaLink :href="route('home')">Home</InertiaLink> </li>
                                <li><a href="fruits.html">Fruits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
                                <li><a href="product.html">Single</a></li>
                                <li> <inertia-link :href="route('Contact-Us')">Contact US</inertia-link> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>  
    </template>
    <script>
    import Dropdown from '@/Shared/Dropdown'
    import Icon from '@/Shared/Icon'
    import Profile from './Profile.vue'
    export default {
        components: {Dropdown,Icon,Profile},
        data() {
            return{
                expanded:false,
                profile:false,
            }
        },     
        methods:{
            OpenProfile(){
                if(this.expanded==false){
                    this.expanded=true;
                }
                else{
                    this.expanded=false;
                }
            },
        }
    }
    </script>
```

profile.vue

```
    <template>
       <div class="contact-page">
            <div>
            <header-content> </header-content>
            </div>
            <div class="table-content">
                <b-container>
                    <div class="table-heading">
                        <h1>User Profile</h1>
                    </div>
                    <b-row>
                        <b-col cols="3">
                            <div class="login-id">
                            <div class="id-img">
                                <b-img src="images/profile.jpg"></b-img>
                            </div>
                            <h2>{{this.$page.auth.user.name}}</h2>
                            </div>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col cols="9">
                            <div class="table-area">
                                <div class="out-layer">
                                    <div class="head">
                                        <h4>User Information</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <b-link>
                                    <div class="pencil">
                                        <b-img src="images/edit.png"></b-img>
                                    </div>
                                    </b-link>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user">
                                    <b-row no-gutters>
                                        <b-col cols="6"><span class="text">NAME</span></b-col>
                                        <b-col cols="6"><span class="link">{{this.$page.auth.user.name}}</span></b-col>
                                    </b-row>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </b-container>
            </div>
              
        <div>
           <footer-content> </footer-content>
       </div>
    </div>
    
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import HeaderContent from './Header.vue';
    import FooterContent from './Footer.vue';
    export default {
        components: {HeaderContent,FooterContent},
        data(){
            return {           
          }
    
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in profile.vue, you don't have to use `this` inside `<template>`.

Are other components you call in profile.vue registered correctly?
Try to remove some portions of code to debug which tags throw the error.

Comment: yes footer components are correctly registered.

Comment: @dvila i tried after remove this, but still have the same problem.

Comment: try also to remove some portions of code until it doesn't throw any error

Comment: it isn't the solution but a good tip, unfortunately I don't see any other error